# Pandas How to merge two dataframes based on two columns and update next column?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge two pandas dataframes and like to merge them based on two columns.

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

# first dataframe
data = np.array([[1, 1, 6],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 9],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z'])
print(df)
   x  y  z
0  1  1  6
1  1  2  2
2  2  1  1
3  2  2  9
4  3  1  1
5  3  2  1

## another dataframe
N = 4
perms = list(product(range(N), range(N)))
x = [i[0] for i in perms]
y = [i[1] for i in perms]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x,'y': y,'z':0})

print(df1)
```

The output should looks like below:

```
    x  y  z  
0   0  0  0  
1   0  1  0  
2   0  2  0  
3   0  3  0  
4   1  0  0  
5   1  1  6  
6   1  2  2  
7   1  3  0  
8   2  0  0  
9   2  1  1 
10  2  2  9  
11  2  3  0  
12  3  0  0  
13  3  1  1  
14  3  2  1  
15  3  3  0
```

**Question** 
How to update values of z column of df1 from dataframe df ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `merge` then `update`

```
df1.update(df1.drop('z',1).merge(df,how='left'))
df1
Out[439]: 
    x  y    z
0   0  0  0.0
1   0  1  0.0
2   0  2  0.0
3   0  3  0.0
4   1  0  0.0
5   1  1  6.0
6   1  2  2.0
7   1  3  0.0
8   2  0  0.0
9   2  1  1.0
10  2  2  9.0
11  2  3  0.0
12  3  0  0.0
13  3  1  1.0
14  3  2  1.0
15  3  3  0.0
```

Comment: @MilkyWay007  Yes, you can `df.set_index(['x','y']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(perms),fill_value=0).reset_index()`

Comment: comment question: Can we directly create the answer if we only know df and permutation N = 4, without intermediate df1?

Comment: Thanks a ton! this method works and demands little more brain to understand the algorithm. I would stick to my dumber way of creating df and df1 and then merging them, which is easier for me to remember in the future.